# Appending Custom Query Parameters to wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to append custom query parameters on to every link inside a wp_nav_menu call.

So after every href in the menu append either ?var1=apple&var2=orange' or '&var1=apple&var2=orange'.

How can I do this?

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => 'nav', 'container_class' => 'nav-menu',
 'menu_class' => 'main-menu main-nav clrf dropdown', 
'theme_location' => 'header', 'enable_bp_links' => true, 'show_home' => true ) );
```

Comment: What did you do so far? Please post your code.

Comment: code posted.  Would I turn echo off and then append to each item?

Comment: I would not call that a try, however, the function you dropped is documented here, probably that's some news for you and helps you: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu - if not, just ignore.

Comment: Yes I know the wp_nav_menu function, but it doesn't include a parameter to add to the href urls.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If there is, then by using a callback function known as action/filter in wordpress. Look inside the source-code of that function and the function it contains if there is any filter you can make use of.

Answer (score 0):

The default nav menu code doesn't have this option.  What you CAN do is create a small plugin that hooks into the nav menu before it gets displayed and use an XML transform to add this to every link.

I've done this before and it worked successfully but I don't have the code nearby right now.  All I can do is promise that this works.  When I next get a chance I'll try to remember to post it.